# MySQL - Get Distinct Primary Col Table Row Order By Foreign Key Table

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

The title may be confusing, here is my schema

[image]

and here is the result of my query

[image]

how can i remove duplicates and just get the values highlighted, i am trying to order by message time

Regards

Comment: What is the rule for duplicates? The most recent wins?

Comment: Is this MS SQL_Server?

Comment: yes @TimSchmelter its sqlserver but i eventually have to run it against mysql

Comment: @PM77-1 i have to get the contact name based on the most recently received messages

Comment: `distinct` is ***not*** a function. It always operates on **all** columns of the select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax will work in both SQL Server and MySQL:

```
SELECT c.ContactID, c.Name, m.Text, m.Messagetime
FROM Contacts c INNER JOIN
     Messages m
     ON c.ContactID = m.ContactID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from messages m2
                  where m2.ContactId = m.ContactId and
                        m2.MessageTime > m.MessageTime
                 )
ORDER BY m.MessageTime desc;
```

Note that if you have duplicate most recent message times, then all will be returned.

Comment: mysql has `Row_Number()`?

Comment: just one thing how can i make it order by messagetime desc? please refer to the highlighted portion of the screenshot.... P.S a million thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way in SQL-Server is using a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT c.ContactID, c.Name, m.Text, m.Messagetime,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ContactID
                                   ORDER BY m.MessageTime DESC)
    FROM dbo.Contacts c
    INNER JOIN Messages m ON c.ContactID = m.ContactID
)
SELECT ContadctId, Name, Text, Messagetime
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: A CTE is similar to a subquery, so you can use one. But if you ask because you want to use it in MySql, that won't work because MySql has no `Row_Number` function. You need to use `Group By`. But i have no time now to show you an example.

Comment: tnx very much im gonna try it

Comment: im getting error `The multi-part identifier "c.contactid" could not be bound.`

Comment: @TimSchmelter tnx for your time :)