# Convert CTE To MySQL Compliant Query

Tags: mysql

Here is my schema

[image]

and here is the result of my query

[image]

how can i remove duplicates and just get the values highlighted, i am trying to order by message time

### [With some Help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24944981/1679410)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT c.ContactID, c.Name, m.Text, m.Messagetime,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ContactID
                                   ORDER BY m.MessageTime DESC)
    FROM dbo.Contacts c
    INNER JOIN Messages m ON c.ContactID = m.ContactID
)
SELECT ContactId, Name, Text, Messagetime
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1 order by messagetime
```

i managed to get the desired result, but how can i convert it so it runs on mysql

Regards

Comment: You cannot. Mysql doesn't support window functions. CTE is not a real problem here since it could easily be replaced with a nested query.

Comment: @zerkms i know that is what im asking i hope the desired result can be achieved without CTE in mysql, please help my sql concept have rusted away...

Comment: CTE is not a problem here - you could replace it with a nested query. But the window function is a problem. So what if you explain the task at first?

Comment: window function? the distinct im using is wrong, i have highlighted the result portion i want, basically i want to get the contacts based on latest messages received (timestamp)...

Comment: i hope i have made myself clear? :| i can send you the script if needed or a fiddle...

Comment: You are looking for a `greatest-n-per-group` type of query, the duplicate should give you plenty of suggestions on how to resolve this.

Comment: @zerkms by window function you meant `ROW_NUMBER()` sry i didnt get you at first